# Updating Multiple Fields (MySQL) with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need to update a field in my database (phone numbers) to a new format. I can do this with mysql, but seeing as its depreciated I was wondering if anyone has any tips on updating multiple fields using mysqli? The number code for the number formater is:

```
function formatPhoneNumber($phoneNumber) {
    $phoneNumber = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','',$phoneNumber);

    if(strlen($phoneNumber) > 10) {
        $countryCode = substr($phoneNumber, 0, strlen($phoneNumber)-10);
        $areaCode = substr($phoneNumber, -10, 3);
        $nextThree = substr($phoneNumber, -7, 3);
        $lastFour = substr($phoneNumber, -4, 4);

        $phoneNumber = '+'.$countryCode.' ('.$areaCode.') '.$nextThree.'-'.$lastFour;
    }
    else if(strlen($phoneNumber) == 10) {
        $areaCode = substr($phoneNumber, 0, 3);
        $nextThree = substr($phoneNumber, 3, 3);
        $lastFour = substr($phoneNumber, 6, 4);

        $phoneNumber = '('.$areaCode.') '.$nextThree.'-'.$lastFour;
    }
    else if(strlen($phoneNumber) == 7) {
        $nextThree = substr($phoneNumber, 0, 3);
        $lastFour = substr($phoneNumber, 3, 4);

        $phoneNumber = $nextThree.'-'.$lastFour;
    }

    return $phoneNumber;
}
```

And query would be `SELECT customers_id, customers_telephone FROM customers WHERE customers_telephone NOT IN (' ')`, there will be close to 20,000 rows affected, what is the most efficient way to do this?

the for loop looks like this, but it is only doing the first customer in the array:

```
foreach($customers as $row)
{
    $customer_id = $row['customers_id'];
    $numbers_array = $row['customers_telephone'];
    function formatPhoneNumber($phoneNumber) {
    $phoneNumber = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','',$phoneNumber);

    if(strlen($phoneNumber) > 10) {
        $countryCode = substr($phoneNumber, 0, strlen($phoneNumber)-10);
        $areaCode = substr($phoneNumber, -10, 3);
        $nextThree = substr($phoneNumber, -7, 3);
        $lastFour = substr($phoneNumber, -4, 4);

        $phoneNumber = '+'.$countryCode.'-'.$areaCode.'- '.$nextThree.'-'.$lastFour;
    }
    else if(strlen($phoneNumber) == 10) {
        $areaCode = substr($phoneNumber, 0, 3);
        $nextThree = substr($phoneNumber, 3, 3);
        $lastFour = substr($phoneNumber, 6, 4);

        $phoneNumber = $areaCode.'- '.$nextThree.'-'.$lastFour;
    }
    else if(strlen($phoneNumber) == 7) {
        $nextThree = substr($phoneNumber, 0, 3);
        $lastFour = substr($phoneNumber, 3, 4);

        $phoneNumber = $nextThree.'-'.$lastFour;
    }

    return $phoneNumber;
}
    formatPhoneNumber($numbers_array);
    echo $numbers_array."  -  ".$customer_id;

}
```

Comment: I would 1)use the select to get all of the phone numbers in the current format and put them in an array. 2) Using a for loop, put all of the numbers through your function, putting them into a new format array. 3) Run an update query for each entry.

Comment: @Brobin I updated my original question, but its only doing the first row, do you see whats wrong with it?

Comment: You can't have the function in the loop. you need to call it from within the loop. Look at @Scott Saunders' answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your function out of your loop.

Then change the last two lines:

```
$formattedNumber = formatPhoneNumber($numbers_array);
echo $formattedNumber . "  -  " . $customer_id;
```